# Should I restrict gem versions when cloning a legacy Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, legacy-app

Most instructions for cloning and running a Rails app just suggest downloading the files and running...

```
bundle install
```

But, if you're dealing with a legacy app already in production, shouldn't you put in the restrictions to make sure you're in sync with the production application? If restrictions weren't placed on the original gems and bundle update hasn't been run on them, won't the "new" development gems potentially be more updated?

Answer (score 0):

You should restrict the gem versions to avoid any incompatibilities (deprecations, method name changes, etc). Bundle will attempt to download the latest version unless one is specified.